# jquery: animate function problem

Tags: jquery

i start learning jquery just yesterday. i have a div element with some content, and i want to hide it by changing it's height:
here is the script

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#hide").click(function(){
            $("#cont").animate({
                height: '0'
                },1500);
            $("#cont").hide();
        });
    });
    </script>

<input type="button" value="hide" id="hide">
<div  id="cont">
text here...
</div>
```

but it doesn't work, becouse it automaticaly sets `display:block` to `#cont` element, so after animation it starts to show.
when i try to set `display:none` to `#cont` element, it doesn't happen.
could you help me? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the  [`slideUp`](http://api.jquery.com/slideUp/) method:

> The `.slideUp()` method animates the height of the matched elements. This causes lower parts of the page to slide up, appearing to conceal the items. Once the height reaches `0`, the display style property is set to `none` to ensure that the element no longer affects the layout of the page.

```
$("#hide").click(function(){
    $("#cont").slideUp();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks Felix Kling, it works:
but just now i find the solution with animate function too:
it looks like this

```
$("#hide").click(function(){
   $("#cont").animate({
    height: '0'
    },1500).hide(1500);
  });
```